# Replacing space from special urls using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm able to replace all `%20` with `-` from url by using :

**.htaccess :**

```
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s+.*)$" $1-$2 [L]
# remove multiple hyphens
RewriteRule ^(.*)-{2,}(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302]
```

Now i want to do this work for only **desired urls** Not all , url's like like :

**Example.com/blog/example%title** => **example.com/blog/example-title**

**Example.com/product/example%product** => **example.com/product/example-product**

How i can do this using `.htaccess` ?

**EDIT :**

Main Problem is that when i upload images to server with **%** in name like `image 1.jpg` url will redirect me to a name like `image-1.jpg` and server can't find image to show

**EDIT 2**

my **.htaccess** have this codes beforehand:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place known prefixes in your rules:

```
RewriteRule "^((?:blog|product)/\S*)\s+(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE,R=302,NC]

RewriteRule "^((?:blog|product)\S*)\s+(\S*\s+.*)$" $1-$2 [L,NC]

# remove multiple hyphens
RewriteRule ^((?:blog|product)/.*)-{2,}(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Not worked ! i tested for this url : `site.com/blog/one/64/how%to%relax` . i want to be `/blog/one/64/how-to-relax` .

Comment: Space character is `%20` not `%`. I have tested with `http://localhost/blog/one/64/how%20to%20relax` that got correctly redirected to `http://localhost/blog/one/64/how-to-relax`

Comment: i meant `%20` , it was typographical mistakes . i copied exactly your code in my .htaccess but not working .

Comment: i had 6 line code before in my .htaccess and i edited my question . maybe releated it ! pls read question **EDITED 2**  part . @anubhava

Comment: i used in `codeigniter` . is about Caching problem or something else ? some urls replaced `%20` with `-` some **NOT** !

Comment: Finally i moved your codes top of everything i had beforehand in `.htaccess` and it worked ! i did not know reason

Comment: Yes indeed all redirect rules should be placed before internal rewrite rules because `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` changes all URIs to `index.php/...`